# Parsing JSON POST data sent from Unity to Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, http, unity-game-engine

I'm building a Rails service for a Unity front end. One of the controllers is having an issue parsing the JSON blob from my `UnityWebRequest`. Here is what Unity says it is sending:

`[StoryPost] Sending request to localhost:3000/stories/new with post data [words, {"_array":[{"_text":"mailing"}]}]`

And here is what Rails is logging when it receives the JSON:

```
Started POST "/stories/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-26 20:08:40 -0400
    Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
    Contents:

    words=%7B%22_array%22%3A%5B%7B%22_text%22%3A%22mailing%22%7D%5D%7D

    ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (743: unexpected token at 'words=%7B%22_array%22%3A%5B%7B%22_text%22%3A%22mailing%22%7D%5D%7D'):

    actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:113:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
    actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:107:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
```

It looks like I have some sort of encoding error. This started happening once I added the following code to my web request:

```
_request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
_request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

If I comment out the two `SetRequestHeader` calls mentioned above, then here is what Rails logs:

```
Started POST "/stories/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-26 23:13:14 -0400
Processing by StoriesController#new as */*
Parameters: {"words"=>"{\"_array\":[{\"_text\":\"inspectors\"}]}"}
```

I added this code so that Rails would automatically know to parse my POST data as JSON. Anyone seen this type of issue before? New to Rails and HTTP, but not to Unity.

#### Relevant Code

For reference, here is my Rails Controller:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController      

    def new
      post_data = params["words"]
      words_array = post_data["_array"];
      puts "words " + words_array
      story = Story.new(words_array)
      story.save()
    end    
end
```

And here is my Unity code. Note: `_PostData` is a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
protected ServiceCall()
        {
            switch (_Type)
            {
                case RequestType.Get:
                    _request = UnityWebRequest.Get(_URL);
                    break;
                case RequestType.Post:
                    _request = UnityWebRequest.Post(_URL, _PostData);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NullReferenceException("Unknown request type " + _Type);
            }

            _request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            _request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            _request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

            Diag.Crumb(this, $"Sending request to {_URL} with post data {_PostData.Pretty()}");

            _requestOperation = _request.Send();
        }
```

Here is how I am building `_PostData`

```
    protected override Dictionary<string, string> _PostData 
    {
        get
        {
            var asArray = new JsonArray<Word>(Luke.GuessWords);
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(asArray);
            return new Dictionary<string, string>{{"words", json}};
        }
    }
```

`JSONArray` is just a simple class that has an `_array` field, because Unity's `JsonUtility` cannot serialize top-level arrays.

Comment: can you change things on the unity side so that it's not the value of `words` that is a json-encoded string, but rather the entire params object being sent? (you'd send the params as a json payload and not in the url)

Comment: maybe you could show the unity code where you send the request

Comment: Sure, edited the Unity code in at the bottom.

Comment: Re: the params object. I believe the entire params object is already a JSON encoded string. Edited again to show the Rails logs for when I remove the request headers.

Comment: Can you show how you're building `_PostData`? I have a hunch you're manually serializing part of it, so the thing is getting double-serialized

Comment: Sure, added! At bottom of post.

Comment: Your entire params object is not JSON already: unescaped, Rails is receiving `words={"_array":[{"_text":"mailing"}]}`. Everything inside `params[:words]` is JSON encoded, but you still have `words=JSON string` and so rails can't parse that as JSON

Comment: Okay, I think that worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the feedback that my entire POST body was not formatted as JSON, I instead changed `_PostData` to return a string, and in my deriving classes serialized `_PostData` to JSON. Then in the base class, I encoded the JSON as bytes and sent it up as the POST body. Here is my changed code:

In Rails:

```
def new
  words_array = params["_array"]
  puts "words " + words_array.to_s
  story = Story.new(words_array)
  puts "story is " + story.to_s
end
```

In Unity:

```
protected override string _PostData 
{
    get
    {
        var asArray = new JsonArray<Word>(Luke.GuessWords);
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(asArray);
        return json;
    }
}
```

And...

```
case RequestType.Post:
    _request = UnityWebRequest.Post(_URL, new Dictionary<string, string>());
    _request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw
    (
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_PostData)
    );
    break;
```